# change varnish cli_buffer param to 10000

Tags: caching, ssh, configuration, varnish, varnish-vcl

I need to change my varnish param cli_buffer to bigger value than the default one (8192).

In the github thread  https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/136

they've already mentioned the following way to do this

> start Varnish instance with "-p cli_buffer 10000"

i tried with the following command but i cant change

> varnishd -p cli_buffer=10000

i guess i need to use vcl.inline, but am not sure how to do that (as i am developer and just a beginner with server stuff like this.)

I have Sudo access to start and stop the varnish and change the varnish config.

Can you help me how to do this ?

Thanks, 
Jerome

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it,

**To change varnish params do the following:**

Assumed that you're logged in to shell as a super user and has permission to change varnish configuration and start and stop the varnish services

use command varnishadm

> varnishadm

After that change the param as shown below

> varnish> param.set cli_buffer 10000

To verify its changed use the command below

> param.show cli_buffer

You are done !

Answer (score 0):

Seems cli_buffer need add to 
/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service

like

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -p feature=+esi_ignore_other_elements -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on -p cli_buffer=16384 -s malloc,256m
```